# Using a class variable in a class extension function

Tags: kotlin

I'm doing a [Kotlin Koans's exercise on collection extension functions](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Collections/Introduction/Task.kt) and am wondering how the variable `customers` can be detected from the function:

```
fun Shop.getSetOfCustomers(): Set<Customer> = customers.toSet()

data class Shop(val name: String, val customers: List<Customer>)

data class Customer(val name: String, val city: City, val orders: List<Order>) {
    override fun toString() = "$name from ${city.name}"
}

data class Order(val products: List<Product>, val isDelivered: Boolean)

data class Product(val name: String, val price: Double) {
    override fun toString() = "'$name' for $price"
}

data class City(val name: String) {
    override fun toString() = name
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're writing an extension function, you can write it *as if* you were inside the class in an actual method. So inside an extension on `Shop`, `this` refers to the `Shop` instance that the extension was called on, and `this.customers` is also available (because it's public, you can't access private members in an extension).

Then, as within the class, you can also omit `this` when referencing a property or function of the same class, hence just `customer` in the extension.

Comment: Thanks, Can you also tell me why I'm getting a Type Inference error here? `fun Shop.checkAllCustomersAreFrom(city: City): Boolean = customers.all(it.city == city)` - the inference is `Boolean` and I'm returning a `Boolean` so it should be working.

Comment: Shouldn't the last set of parens (round brackets) be braces (curly brackets)?

Comment: Thanks that worked - but why is it in curly brackets? @gidds The docs have rounded brackets: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/all.html